# Dockerfile - activate Python virtualvenv - ubuntu

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create an Docker Image that contains an Apache Webserver with Django. I am using virtual environments in my production environment and I don't know how to activate it in a Dockerfile.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/apache
ARG GITLAB_USERNAME
ARG GITLAB_TOKEN

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 libpq-dev git
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
WORKDIR "/var/www"
RUN git clone https://${GITLAB_USERNAME}:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/g5362/gnsave.git
RUN mv gnsave/Netto\ umgeschrieben/ ./GNSave
RUN rm -r gnsave
WORKDIR "/GNSave/"
RUN virtualenv gnsave
RUN source gnsave/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN a2enmod wsgi
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/GNSave
RUN chmod -R u+w /var/www/GNSave
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/GNSave/assets
COPY django.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/django.conf
RUN a2dissite 000-default
RUN a2ensite django
RUN /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

The error messae I get is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

My question is if I should split the django and apache into two dockers and compose them or if there is a workaround for activation venvs in my Dockerfile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Splitting the two separate processes into two separate containers is usually a good approach.  You don't need a virtual environment in the dedicated Django container; you can use the "system" Python there, and it will be isolated from the host's Python and Pythons in other containers.

Comment: Quick question: Why do you need to create a virtual environment inside docker, it it's already isolated from your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain your error message, it's because by default, Docker runs these commands with `/bin/sh`. `source` is a Bash command. You have two options:

1. Specify using Bash as the shell to run these commands by adding `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` before the RUN commands
2. Use the dot operator: `RUN . gnsave/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt`